# Postgres 9.0 + translate function and ascii codes

Tags: postgresql, escaping, standards

I use the translate function to process searches accent insensitive.
To improve this request, i've created a matching index :

```
CREATE INDEX person_lastname_ci_ai_si
ON person
USING btree
(translate(upper(lastname::text), '\303\200\303\201\303\202\303\203\303\204\303\205\303\206\303\207\303\210\303\211\303\212\303\213\303\214\303\215\303\216\303\217\303\221\303\222\303\223\303\224\303\225\303\226\303\230\303\231\303\232\303\233\303\234\303\235\303\237\303\240\303\241\303\242\303\243\303\244\303\245\303\246\303\247\303\250\303\251\303\252\303\253\303\254\303\255\303\256\303\257\303\261\303\262\303\263\303\264\303\265\303\266\303\270\303\271\303\272\303\273\303\274\303\275\303\277'::text, 'AAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYSaaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy'::text)
);
```

It works fine with postgres 9.1 but it seems to don't work with 9.0.
Postgres 9.0 seems to replace

```
'\303\200\303\201\303\202\303\203\303\204\303\205\303\206\303\207\303\210\303\211\303\212\303\213\303\214\303\215\303\216\303\217\303\221\303\222\303\223\303\224\303\225\303\226\303\230\303\231\303\232\303\233\303\234\303\235\303\237\303\240\303\241\303\242\303\243\303\244\303\245\303\246\303\247\303\250\303\251\303\252\303\253\303\254\303\255\303\256\303\257\303\261\303\262\303\263\303\264\303\265\303\266\303\270\303\271\303\272\303\273\303\274\303\275\303\277'
```

by

```
ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ
```

Then, because my code perform searches using ascii codes, it doesn't use the index..

Is there a way to avoid postgres to convert ascii codes to characters when creating index ?

For example :

```
select '\303\200\303\201\303\202\303\203\303\204\303\205\303\206\303\207\303\210\303\211\303\212\303\213\303\214\303\215\303\216\303\217\303\221\303\222\303\223\303\224\303\225\303\226\303\230\303\231\303\232\303\233\303\234\303\235\303\237\303\240\303\241\303\242\303\243\303\244\303\245\303\246\303\247\303\250\303\251\303\252\303\253\303\254\303\255\303\256\303\257\303\261\303\262\303\263\303\264\303\265\303\266\303\270\303\271\303\272\303\273\303\274\303\275\303\277'
```

;

Result

```
ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ
```

How can i have this result ?

```
\303\200\303\201\303\202\303\203\303\204\303\205\303\206\303\207\303\210\303\211\303\212\303\213\303\214\303\215\303\216\303\217\303\221\303\222\303\223\303\224\303\225\303\226\303\230\303\231\303\232\303\233\303\234\303\235\303\237\303\240\303\241\303\242\303\243\303\244\303\245\303\246\303\247\303\250\303\251\303\252\303\253\303\254\303\255\303\256\303\257\303\261\303\262\303\263\303\264\303\265\303\266\303\270\303\271\303\272\303\273\303\274\303\275\303\277
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 9.1, PostgreSQL [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) option defaults to `ON`.

This means that backslash `\` character is treated as-is and not as escaping symbol, this is done to prevent SQL injection attacks; this follows SQL standard recommendations.
It is still possible to use `\` to get special characters, but only within [string constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE).

For the pre-9.1 versions of PostgreSQL I suppose these options are possible:

1. Change system-wide `standard_conforming_strings` option to `ON`, but this will affect whole cluster and may give unexpected results in other areas;
2. Change `standard_conforming_strings` option on a [per-user basis](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterrole.html), using `ALTER ROLE ... SET standard_conforming_strings TO on;`, this one also may have side effects;
3. Use plain `SET standard_conforming_strings TO on;` as a first command you issue in your session before creating the index;
4. Double all your backslashes so that are treated as a literal `\` symbol in your `CREATE INDEX ...` statement.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. select '\303\200\303\201\303\202\303\(...)' return '\303\200\303\201\303\202\303\(...)' -> good. But create index person_firstnamebegin_ci_ai_si ON person USING btree (translate(substr(upper(replace(firstname::text, ' '::text, ''::text)), 1, 1), '\\303\\200\\303\\201\\303\\202\\303\\203\\303\\204\\303(...) create an index with doubled slash values instead of simple slash even if I create index with single slashes

Comment: PGADMIN displays index with double slahes instead of simple slashes but my searches uses the created index well. Thanks for your help